# Handle Duplicate Record in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with records like below

```
NAME        STATUS          xml_configparamdb_id      xml_configuration_id
STO         INACTIVE                  1                        1
STO         ACTIVE                    1                        2
BOS         ACTIVE                    1                        3
KYC         INACTIVE                  1                        4 
KYC         INACTIVE                  1                        5
ACC         ACTIVE                    1                        6
ACC         ACTIVE                    1                        7
```

Now result I am interested in is as follows:

```
NAME        STATUS          xml_configparamdb_id      xml_configuration_id

STO         ACTIVE                    1                        2
BOS         ACTIVE                    1                        3
KYC         INACTIVE                  1                        4 
ACC         ACTIVE                    1                        6
```

That is, I want to select data on basis of STATUS .

1. Condition -- If STATUS is ACTIVE for both case of same Parameter - select first coming ACTIVE
2. Condition -- If STATUS is INACTIVE for both case of same Parameter - select first coming INACTIVE
3. Condition -- If STATUS is ACTIVE & INACTIVE for same Parameter - select ACTIVE

Now I used below query to populate result like above without using PRIMARY KEY Column (xml_configuration_id)

```sql
CURSOR cCnfgTypData IS
  select distinct name, description, STATUS
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  WHERE process_exec_num = 1
  AND STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  UNION ALL
  select name, description, STATUS
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration t
  where process_exec_num = 1
  and STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
  and not exists (select * from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  where name = t.name 
  and STATUS = 'ACTIVE') order by name, description;
```

It's showing fine data. But when I execute using PRIMARY KEY Column (xml_configuration_id) like below it's displaying all data without satisfying condition

```sql
  select distinct name, description, STATUS, xml_configparamdb_id, xml_configuration_id
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  WHERE process_exec_num = 1
  AND STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
  UNION ALL
  select name, description, STATUS, xml_configparamdb_id, xml_configuration_id
  from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration t
  where process_exec_num = 1
  and STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
  and not exists (select * from stg_xml_cpdb_configuration
  where name = t.name 
  and STATUS = 'ACTIVE') order by name, description;
```

Comment: For reference, http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/196051/

Comment: To explain why you are having trouble, the distinct keyword applies across all selected columns, because xml_config_id is unique for each row, distinct will return each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use analytic function `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SQL> SELECT name,
  2    status,
  3    xml_configparamdb_id,
  4    xml_configuration_id
  5  FROM
  6    ( SELECT t.*, row_number() over (partition BY name order by status) rn FROM t
  7    )
  8  WHERE rn = 1
  9  ORDER BY xml_configuration_id
 10  /

NAM STATUS   XML_CONFIGPARAMDB_ID XML_CONFIGURATION_ID
--- -------- -------------------- --------------------
STO ACTIVE                      1                    2
BOS ACTIVE                      1                    3
KYC INACTIVE                    1                    4
ACC ACTIVE                      1                    6

SQL>
```